# How to remove options in react quill

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I have the quill text editor displayed, but I'd like to remove some options in the toolbar.
Are there some props I can disable to remove the specific options I'd like to remove?

[image]

I'd like to remove whatever the Tx is on the far right and the attachment icon.

```
const Postdescription = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    return (
        <div className="postdescriptioncontainer">
            <div className="postdescription">
                <ReactQuill theme="snow" value={value} onChange={setValue}/>
                <div>{Parser(value)}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually pretty straightforward:

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";

export const TextEditor: FC = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <ReactQuill
        value={text}
        onChange={setText}
        modules={{ toolbar: ["bold"] }}
      />
    </>
  );
```

This gives you a toolbar with only one option, which is the toggle for bold text.

It's also demo'd in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill#custom-toolbar